# An equivalent definition for contact pair manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, contact-geometry

**َContact manifold**

> A $(2n + 1)$-dimensional manifold $M$ is said to be a contact manifold if it
>   admits a global 1-form $\eta$ such that $\eta\wedge (d\eta)^n\neq 0$.

There is an equivalent definition by J. W. Gray:

> A manifold admit an almost contact structure if the structural group
>   of the tangent bundle is reducible to $U(n)\times 1$.

**Contact pairs manifold**

> A pair $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ of $1$-forms on a manifold is said to be a contact pair of type $(h,k)$ if
>   $$\alpha_1 \wedge (d\alpha_1)^h \wedge\alpha_2 \wedge(d\alpha_2)^k\ \text{ is a volume form,}\\
> (d\alpha_1)^{h+1} = 0\ \text{and}\  (d\alpha_2)^{k+1} = 0.$$

**Question:** Is there an equivalent definition for contact pair similar to contact case?

Thanks.

Comment: In your first definition you need to assume that $M$ is orientable. The second definition is of *almost contact structure*, according to Gray [MR0112161].

Comment: @JarekKędra, Thanks for your accuracy.

Comment: Notic that  every almost contact manifold is orientable. [Yano, Kon, Structure on manifolds, p. 255]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jarek said, the two definitions that you give are definitely *NOT* equivalent: the definition by Gray is about *almost* contact structures which is a much weaker notion than a proper contact structure!

Maybe you would be interested in an *almost* contact pair like $TM$ splits into $\mathbb{R}\oplus E_1\oplus \mathbb{R}\oplus E_2$, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are complex bundles of (complex) dimensions $h$ and $k$ respectively.  Is this useful for anything? I don't know.